# Pandas parser CParseError

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using pandas to read a csv file. I am getting this error:

```
File "antifraud.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(trainFilePath, names=['time', 'id1', 'id2', 'amount', 'message'])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 470, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 256, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 715, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1164, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 758, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7411)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 780, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:7651)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 833, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8268)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 820, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8142)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1758, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:20728)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

When I tried to read it using open csv as:

```
import csv
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    linenumber = 1
    try:
        for row in reader:
            linenumber += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print (("Error line %d: %s %s" % (linenumber, str(type(e)), e.message)))
```

I saw that the error was at a particular line. The line is:

```
2016-11-02 09:45:43, 10244, 26248, 20.06, 提供一天 我充滿
```

My question is that is the data in the file having some escape characters like '\r','\n' or is it because maybe pandas cannot read Chinese as I haven't mentioned an encoding method, or is it something else?

Comment: what is the encoding (or code page) of your `trainFilePath`?

Comment: @MaxU The encoding of the file is Unicode

Comment: Try this hack: `pd.read_csv(open(trainFilePath,'rU'), encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reported [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11166) and as a solution one can try the following solution provided by @chris-b1:

```
pd.read_csv(open(trainFilePath,'rU'), encoding='utf-8')
```